# Regex match pattern more than once in the same line

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to perform this transformation to a string (using javascript):

Input:

```
[hello]{world}and[good]{night}
```

Output:

```
<span class="top">hello<span class="bottom">world</span></span>and<span class="top">good<span class="bottom">night</span></span>
```

To do that I am using the following regex:

```
text.replace(/\[(.*)\]\{(.*)\}/gim, "<span class='top'>$1<span class='bottom'>$2</span></span>")
```

It works correctly when only setting one occurrence of the pattern in a string `[hello]{world}`

But if I add a string with more than one, the regex matches the first `[]` and the last `{}` instead, and prints this:

```
<span class='top'>hello]{world}and[good<span class='bottom'>night</span></span>
```

How can I tell regex to match the first pattern and the second pattern instead of matching it as one bigger pattern?

Note that between the `[]` and `{}` I expect there to be no text. So `[hello]world and good{night}` should not be matched.

Comment: Can there be strings like`[hi] and then [hello]{world}and[good]{night}`?

Comment: Yes, that could be the case

Comment: Then you need `/\[([^\][]*)]\{([^{}]*)}/g`, i.e. negated character classes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your comment answered my question correctly. Not sure why it is marked as duplicate, because the replies on the other question do not solve one of the problems I was facing. But anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `?` after `.*` to make the quantifier lazy, instead of greedy.

```js
const text = '[hello]{world}and[good]{night}'


const result = text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]\{(.*?)\}/gim, "<span class='top'>$1<span class='bottom'>$2</span></span>")


console.log(result)
```